# ASP.NET MVC3: password protect a page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, passwords

Hello in an MVC3 application,
I want to put a password on a page.

The page is accessible from an action link that calls an ActionResult in the controller. And returns the view with the model.

What is the best way or easiest way to add a password to the page.

Something like a popup that shows and you have to put a password and if you put the wrong password you don't see the page (the view is not loaded)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put a filter on the page's get action.

look at the following link

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs